# Loading a 2nd DIV on submit button click on the 1st DIV leaving the 1st DIV visible on the same page

Tags: php, css

I have 2 DIV. They are linked forms.

First Div have 2 dropdowns for user input with a submit button. When user selects the submit button, another DIV will appear.

The first DIV will still remain there so users can change their input and the 2nd Div selection will also be updated once submit is selected. Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Do you want multi-step form ? http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar visit the link mentioned and let me know if it helps

Comment: Yes but some div will only appear if a certain button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to see your approach on that. However, it's pretty simple. Just don't treat the button in first div as form submission.

Run only the validation for the first div on button click. And, have only one form through out. I don't see any reason to use multiple forms if you are allowing users to change content later.

Comment: $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("report") or die ("no database");

$sql11 = "SELECT `TABLE_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`tables` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='report'";
$result = mysql_query($sql11);
 
echo '<select name=dropdown id=operators>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['TABLE_NAME'].'">'.$row['TABLE_NAME'].'</option>';

}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">';

Comment: This is to show the tables name from database. Column names will be generated based on the table name selecting in the next div. So when users change the table names in the first DIV and click submit, the second DIV with column names will automatically change.